# Flutter: base.copyWith() applying custom theme name or property

Tags: flutter

```
  TextTheme _basicTextTheme(TextTheme base) {
    return base.copyWith(
        headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        bodyText1: GoogleFonts.lato(
            fontSize: 20, color: Colors.orange),
        bodyText2: GoogleFonts.lato(
          fontSize: 15.0,
        ));
  }
```

I have succeed to apply this to my themeData. Is there anyway that I can create a custom field to it? Like

`linkText: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 20)`

So far, I have distinguished using `headline and bodyText 1 2 3` but then it is a bit confusing right now. I want to create a custom name that I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *extension* on *TextTheme*

```
extension CustomTextStyles on TextTheme {   
    TextStyle get linkText {
        return TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        );   
    } 

    TextStyle get buttonText{
        return TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        );   
    }  
}
```

Comment: How can I apply this in the `Text()` widget?

Comment: You can use `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.linkText`